# PHP mixed format date/time - day of the week and time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

So, I am working on a PHP scheduler for seminars.  Basically I have a list of seminars that each meet once per week at the same time on the same day, and run a set number of weeks.

Right now in my database I have the pkey, the start date, the end date, the name of the seminar, and a string representing the day and time.

Right now I have a page showing all seminars currently running based on comparing today's date to the start and end dates of all seminars.  Now I want it JUST to show seminars meeting today.

I assume I will need to make the schedule variable a DATE.  The varchar string was a dect tape fix because I do not even know where to start with this part.

How do I format the SQL variable to store the day and time in a DATE type variable that is in the format [weekday] [time]?  Is this possible?

EDIT

Can somebody who understands what I am asking help me reword my question?  It seems like I can not make what I am asking clear.

For example let's say there are MySQL seminars are Wednesdays at 7pm starting 11/14 and ending 12/26.  I have Wednesdays 7pm saved as a VARCHAR string, and StartDate and EndDate saved as dates.  Right now I have no problem listing all seminars currently in progress, but I would like to filter those by ONLY those meeting on the day of the week that corresponds to the current weekday.  To do this I need to turn 'Wednesday 7pm' into a DATE variable while still keeping the exact same format for echoing on the schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody was able to understand my question here, I will answer it myself.  After talking with a few professionals and instructors I know (who had no problem understanding what I wanted...), I have found that it technically impossible, but a workaround is to select an arbitrary date that falls on that weekday, and use it as a standin, then always present it in weekday format.

Answer (score 2):

Storing dates as a string is discouraged. MySQL includes many [Date / Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You should store this data as a [DateTime datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) and manipulate it using one of these functions.

For example:

```
-- returns 1 for Monday
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%w');
```

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that as a placeholder while I built all the parts of the code that I knew how to do.  Now I have to go back and replace it with an actual DATETIME, my question is how do I format that DATETIME to show Weekday Hour:Minute?m

Comment: As noted in my answer, [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL takes 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' for datetime and 'YYYY-MM-DD' for a date format.

Depending on how you want to store it, you can just add the DATE column and then do an update:

update TABLE set datecolumn = 'date_string_col';

as long as the varchar col you have now has it stored in the appropriate format, otherwise, you will have to change the format to the specified one.

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my issue is with formatting the DATETIME variable to show a DAY OF THE WEEK rather than any specific date, if that is even possible, and then displaying all rows in the table where the DATETIME weekday is the same as the current weekday, and the current calendar date falls between the start and end dates for the term.

Comment: sure, You can do that know that you have the data parsed, you just need to compare against the values of $day for the week using: datecol between $FIRSTDAY and $LASTDAY